# SQL # of days between different date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I count the number of days between a start and end date in SQL?

```
ID      |  START  | END
1       |2018-1-1 |2018-1-3
2       |2018-1-1 |2018-1-4
3       |2018-1-1 |2018-1-5
```

Ideally would return:

```
DATE      | COUNT
2018-1-1  | 3
2018-1-2  | 3
2018-1-3  | 3
2018-1-4  | 2
2018-1-5  | 1
```

Comment: what is the dbms you are using?

Comment: What is `COUNT` ?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to generate all dates between `min` start and `max` end with a recursive cte and then count them.

```
with dates(dt1,dt2) as (select min([start]),max([end]) 
                        from tbl
                        union all
                        select dateadd(day,1,dt1),dt2 
                        from dates
                        where dt1 < dt2
                       )
select d.dt1,count(*)
from dates d
join tbl t on d.dt1 between t.[start] and t.[end]
group by d.dt1
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach worked out with a complete example:

```
DECLARE @range TABLE
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    s_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    e_date DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @range 
    (s_date, e_date)
VALUES 
    ('2018-1-1','2018-1-3'),
    ('2018-1-1','2018-1-4'),
    ('2018-1-1','2018-1-5');

DECLARE @date TABLE 
(
    date DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @date
    (date)
VALUES
    ('2018-1-1'), ('2018-1-1'), ('2018-1-1'),
    ('2018-1-2'), ('2018-1-2'), ('2018-1-2'),
    ('2018-1-3'), ('2018-1-3'), ('2018-1-3'),
    ('2018-1-4'), ('2018-1-4'),
    ('2018-1-5');

SELECT d.date, COUNT(DISTINCT r.id)
FROM @range r
JOIN @date d ON d.date BETWEEN r.s_date AND r.e_date
GROUP BY d.date
```

Answer (score 0):

I post a solution to fill gaps with a simple generator:

[Check it at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8a15/3)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table d
( ID int,    fSTART date,  fEND date );
insert into d values 
(1,       '2018-1-1' ,'2018-1-3'),
(2,       '2018-1-1' ,'2018-1-4'),
(3,       '2018-1-1' ,'2018-1-5');
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH Nbrs_3( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 0 ),
Nbrs_2( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_3 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_3 n2 ),
Nbrs_1( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_2 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_2 n2 ),
Nbrs_0( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_1 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_1 n2 ),
Nbrs ( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_0 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_0 n2 ),
ns (n) as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM Nbrs )
select distinct dateadd( day, n-1,fSTART )
from d inner join ns on dateadd( day, n-1, fSTART ) between fStart and fend
order by 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8a15/3/0)**:

```
|            |
|------------|
| 2018-01-01 |
| 2018-01-02 |
| 2018-01-03 |
| 2018-01-04 |
| 2018-01-05 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I used cross apply to get your results:

I am assuming you want to know how many times that date is between a start and end date of the other table.

Setup:

```
declare @s table
( ID int,    fSTART date,  fEND date );
insert into @s values 
(1,       '2018-1-1' ,'2018-1-3'),
(2,       '2018-1-1' ,'2018-1-4'),
(3,       '2018-1-1' ,'2018-1-5');


declare @d table
(dte date)
insert into @d
values
('1/1/2018')
,('1/2/2018')
,('1/3/2018')
,('1/4/2018')
,('1/5/2018')
```

The Query:

```
select d.dte
    ,ct = sum(case when d.dte between s.fstart and s.fend then 1 else 0 end)
from @d d
cross apply @s s
group by dte
```

results:

```
dte ct
2018-01-01  3
2018-01-02  3
2018-01-03  3
2018-01-04  2
2018-01-05  1
```